# Python process memory and Memcache memory. Is python using the memory address or it copies data?

Tags: python, memory, memcached, shared

The situation - I have 2 computers, the first one has python and second one has memcache. There is some key in memcache, which references to the object in memory which size is 1 GB approximately. If I access that object from python and want to run through, does it mean that python process will copy the whole object to the local memory ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it does. Note that the memcached folks do not recommend storing anything larger than 1 megabyte, so you're well above that recommendation.